# Creating MYSQL rows in ascending order

Tags: mysql

The following code creates rows in a MYSQL table but returns them in descending order.

How can I make it return values in ascending order?

```
   INSERT INTO
        rent
        (
        id
        )
    select @s:=@s+1 as seq
    FROM (SELECT @s:=399) AS baseview, rent
    WHERE @s<1000;
```

Comment: No, nor do I. You seem to want an `INSERT` statement to _return_ values, but `INSERT` _inserts_ values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an ORDER BY clause using the column that determines the order when you SELECT.

```
ORDER BY x ASC
```

Order means nothing when you INSERT.  You should not know or care about how it's stored underneath.  SQL is declarative - worry about what is done, not how.

Comment: `INSERT INTO
        rent
        (
        id
        )
    select @s:=@s+1 as seq
    FROM (SELECT @s:=399) AS baseview, rent
    WHERE @s<1000;
ORDER BY id ASC`

Answer (score -2):

If the `id` field is a Primary Key, they will be returned in ascending order by default. Alternatively, force it with `order by id asc`.

Comment: There is no inherent ordering in a relation, primary key or no (though you may get "lucky" and see an abstraction leak)

Comment: -1 for assuming there is an implied or default order in any table in any RDBMS

Comment: Then explain why 100% of the time, when no `order by` clause is present, the result set is returned in increasing order by the primary key (regardless of the key's type - even primary keys with multiple fields).